# deselect rows of a grid in Extjs 3

Tags: grid, extjs3, selectall

I have a grid and a button that makes me select all the rows of this grid (mygrid.getSelectionModel().selectAll())
But i want that when all the rows are selected and i click to this button it deselct all the rows.
How can i do it ?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 10):

instead of using clearSelections() use deselectAll() as the former is now deprecated.

```
new Ext.Button({
   enableToggle:true,
   toggleHandler:function(btn,state){
      var grid = Ext.getCmp(YOURGRIDID),
      if(state==true){
         grid.getSelectionModel().selectAll()
      }else{
         grid.getSelectionModel().deselectAll()
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

You should enable the toggle option for the button.
here is an example:

```
new Ext.Button({
   enableToggle:true,
   toggleHandler:function(btn,state){
      var grid = Ext.getCmp(YOURGRIDID),
      if(state==true){
         grid.getSelectionModel().selectAll()
      }else{
         grid.getSelectionModel().clearSelections()
      }
   }
})
```